# Python: ++ operator

Tags: python, operators, increment

I often require doding a simple 1 unit incrementation (++) in Python.

I never seem to find a better solution than

```
x = x + 1
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is expecting Python to be C.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Python doesn't have a `++` operator. You should use the `+=` operator:

```
x += 1
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer you are looking for is:

```
x += 1
```